# Fix Eclipse Pydev Text Highlight Color issue

Tags: eclipse, text, pydev, highlight

I have Eclipse SimRel (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0), Build id: 20180917-1800). I have PyDev installed in it from Marketplace.

When using PyDev, if i move my cursor to a specific piece of text, it highlights it in this blindingly unreadable yellowish-white color. See screenshot. How do i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure that color in the preferences.

i.e.: Go to `general > editors > text editors > annotations > Occurrences (PyDev)` and change the color to a different color.